# Removed space bar to clean, now it doesnt want to work!

Tags: keyboard, ergonomics

I removed the space bar to clean my MS Natural Ergonomic 7000 and now I cant get the thing to work effectively when I type! I have to hit directly in the center, and it's hard to push. What the heck did I do??

Answer (score 3):

Wide keys generally have a hinged metal bar which ensures that the key moves straight down wherever you press it. It should be in a “C” shape and nearly as long as the key, and may be attached to the space bar or to the keyboard base.

In either case, there will be two loose hooks in the plastic of the other part. Make sure that both ends of the bar are on their hinges (it may have popped out when you removed the key) and under the hooks as you press the keycap onto the keyboard. And don't bend it — it's only as strong as a good paperclip!

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure that there isn't a bit of plastic that got moved when you cleaned it? The fact that it's hard to press down points to it not fitting in there well enough.

Try taking it off again and pressing on the trigger without the button and see if that works.